# Android minSdkVersion

Tags: android

I wrote a program that worked perfectly until the market required me to add 'minSdkVersion'.  Since I was using 2.3.3 capabilities I set it at 10,but then my program stopped being able to access files from the disk (all file access is false though it works without 'minSdkVersion').  Changing it to require API 1 fixed the functionality but now inadequate OS versions can download it.  Should the 'minSdkVersion' be able to change actual functionality?  Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: What do you mean by saying that "all file access is false "?

Comment: Access,delete,etc. Return false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume when you say "access files" you mean on the SD card.
In this case, you need to add 2 new permissions:

```
    <uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
    <uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

These permissions weren't added until API level 4, so anything below that gets them for free.

Comment: Now that makes sense.  I cant test till wednesday, but ill let you guys know/vote then.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should set minSdkVersion to the lowest **adequate** OS version for your app. Don't forget to also set targetSdkVersion to the highest level for which your app has been tested.

Comment: Technically 10 is required by some of the functions, but when i set 10 the basic file functionality breaks.  Anything higher than 1 and i cant access files.

Comment: Anything in logcat when the file access fails?

Comment: No i had to check the return values of delete and access.  Both were false causing the functions to cease working.